# Add notification to custom ribbon button excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have developed a custom tab in Excel using XML. Is there a way to add notifications to the buttons?

**Actual:**

[image]

**Request:**

[image]

*Edit:*

**I've tried the following:**

```
    ribbonXml = ribbonXml + "<mso:button id=""newProjectPN"" enabled=""true"" label=""Presentation Meeting (NOK)"" image=""GetImage"" size=""large"" onAction=""newProjectPN"" visible=""true"" />"

 Public Sub GetImage(ByVal control As Office.IRibbonControl, ByRef image)
     Set image = LoadPicture("C:\Users\peet\Desktop\teste.png")
 End Sub
```

Comment: By changing the button's picture perhaps?

Comment: @KostasK. the pictures are coming from windows library `imagemso`. not sure how I can add my own pictures.

Comment: Yes you can. You have two options a) imageMso (built-in) or custom picture. Plenty of examples on the net but see this to get you started: https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s2/win009.htm

Comment: Can't get this working. Please see my edited post.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is simply to rebuild the ribbon every time you have a notification, by changing the icon correspondingly.

A drawback will be that you will need quite a few icons, if you want to see the exact number of the notifications as well.

Comment: the icons are coming from windows library `imagemso`. not sure how I can add my own icons.

Comment: @peetman - google **how to add own icons in excel ribbon**. Or read this - https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s2/win009.htm

Comment: cheers, but the examples I find are using CustomUI Editor which I don't have due to company restrictions.

Comment: @peetman - the CustomUI Editor is a good tool indeed, but you can go around it - you only need a text editor like Notepad and knowledge what to write there.

Comment: I've tried some code but it's not working. Please see my edited post.